# How to redirect the admin page in Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.0 template.
How to redirect the backend admin page.

present i'm login to **domainname.com/index.php/admin**

but, i want to ask for **domainname.com/admin**

Answer (score 1):

Followings are the steps:

**1. Login to admin panel**

**2. Click the System->Configuration tab**

[image]

**3. On the appeared screen click "Web" tab under "General" on the left hand side of your admin panel. You will see the below screen:**

[image]

**4. Now set the "Use Web Server Rewrites" option under "Search Engines Optiomization" to "Yes".**

**5. Then, set the "Use Secure URLs in Frontend" option under "Secure" to "Yes". Click "Save Config" button in the top right:**

[image]

**6. Now we need to create an .htaccess file with the rewrite directives in the root of your Magento installation. You may use your hosting control panel File Manager or FTP to create a file.**

Put the following code in the created file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In case your Magento is installed in sub-folder, e.g. ‘shop’, you should use the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**7. Save the file and check your website.**
*The ‘index.php’ is successfully removed from the URL.*

Answer (score 0):

Put this code .htaccess in your magento root

```
   DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

    php_flag session.auto_start off

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

    AddDefaultCharset Off

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

All steps are mentioned on below url

http://magentowebmaster.blogspot.in/2013/11/magento-admin-url-rewrite-set.html

Answer (score 0):

Before you start make sure the Apache rewrites module is enabled, and then follow the steps below.

1) Log-in to your Magento administration area then go to '**System > Configuration > Web**'.

2) Navigate to the '**Unsecure**' and '**Secure**' tabs. Make sure the '**Unsecured**' and '**Secure**' - '**Base Url**' options have your domain name within it, and do not leave the forward slash off at the end of the URL. **Example: http://www.yourdomain.in/**

3) While still on the '**Web**' page, navigate to '**Search Engine Optimisation**' tab and select '**YES**' underneath the '**Use Web Server Rewrites**' option.

4) Navigate to the '**Secure**' tab again (if not already on it) and select '**Yes**' on the '**Use Secure URLs in Frontend**' option.

5) NoW go to the root of your Magento website folder and use this code for your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Save the .htaccess and replace the original file. **(PLEASE MAKE SURE TO BACKUP YOUR ORIGINAL .htaccess FILE BEFORE MESSING WITH IT!!!)**

6) Now go to '**System > Cache Management**' and select all fields and make sure the '**Actions**' dropdown is set on '**Refresh**', then submit. (This will of course refresh the Cache.)